# How to best model a tree of generic content types in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django API for managing a bunch of content related to D&D campaigns: characters, locations, factions, quests, etc. Until now the frontend has always displayed these types of content in their own tabs, so a list of characters, another list of locations, and within a tab content can be nested: locations can have sub-locations, but they are all in their own "silo".

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="map-location-dot")
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
```

I am thinking about turning the frontend into one nested tree of all content types: so a location could have nested factions, which could have nested characters, and so on, totally free-form.

I'm not really sure how to best model this in the database. One idea I have is to create a brand new model that contains the tree, with generic relations to content items via the contenttypes framework from Django.

```py
class Tree(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    parent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    parent_content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
```

That would work (although I am not sure the `GenericForeignKey` would work with nullable fields?), and I could keep all my existing content models in place, I'd just remove their `parent` field, since that's now handled by the `Tree` model. But I am afraid this is incredibly inefficient when it comes to queries. Like let's say the tree for a particular D&D campaign contains 200 items, fetching the entire tree with all the models would probably not be possible in one query, or can it?

Another option is to modify each content model to add a `GenericForeignKey` field for the parent, and an `order` field.. but that seems very dumb.

Or I could have a simple `Content` model with all the common fields. For example, all the content types have a title, subtitle, icon, text, author, created date, etc. Then the `parent` field would again be a simple `ForeignKey` to `self`. And then add a field for the content type in this model, and store the non-common fields in another table (for example, a quest has an `is_completed` field). But that seems like it would end up in just as many queries? Unless I store all the fields for all content types in this one `Content` table and just make them all nullable. Then everything is one big table and can easily be queried.

Is this better than the `Tree` idea from above? Are there other (better?) options to model this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, because all my content models share like 80% of the fields amongst them, I went with the `Content`, and added all the fields from all the models in it, together with a `type` field. This makes querying a lot simpler and faster, gives me a lot of flexibly with what can be a parent of what without having to other tables, and it massively reduces the code in my project as well.

Probably not the best generic way to structure a tree, but in this case it was a good simple solution the fit the problem.